# Can I pass a reference to a map where the data is a pointer to a derived class?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a reference to a map where the data is a pointer to a derived class?

```
  #include <map>

  class B {

  public:

  private:
    int x_;
  };

  class D : public B {

  public:

  private:
    int y_;
  };

  typedef std::map<int, B*> mapB_t;
  typedef std::map<int, D*> mapD_t;

  void foo(mapB_t& inmap) {
    ;
  }

  int main() {
    mapB_t mapB;
    mapD_t mapD;

    mapB[0] = new B;
    mapD[0] = new D;

    foo(mapB);
    foo(mapD);

    return 0;
  }
```

I receive this compiler error:

q.cc: In function 'int main()':
q.cc:34: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'mapB_t&' from   expression of type 'mapD_t'
q.cc:22: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void foo(mapB_t&)'

Comment: The compiler error is a good indication that you can't do this.

Comment: I think the explanation should be that even though polymorphism allows one to pass a `D` type object to a `B&` type reference, `mapB_t` and `mapD_t` have no inheritance relationship. Therefore `mapB_t&` does not accept `mapD_t`.

Comment: Consider what could happen: `inmap[0] = new B;` would be a disaster.

Comment: The right way of using polymorphism in your situation should be to create many objects of `B` and `D` types, but always define the map to be of type `mapB_t`. A `B*` type pointer can point to either `B` or `D`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation should be that even though polymorphism allows one to pass a `D` type object to a `B&` type reference, `mapB_t` and `mapD_t` have no inheritance relationship. Therefore `mapB_t&` does not accept `mapD_t`. The right way of using polymorphism in your situation might be to create many objects of `B` and `D` types, but always define the map to be of type `mapB_t`. A `B*` type pointer can point to either `B` or `D`. You need to define in class `B` at least one `virtual` function to allow the function `foo` to tell if an object pointed to by the `B*` pointer is a `B` or a `D`. Here's the code:

```
  class B{
    private:
      int x_;
    public:
      virtual ~B(){}     // Only for telling the identity of an object
  };
  class D: public B{
    private:
      int y_;            // Virtual destructor gets automatically inherited
  };
```

Then the function `foo` can tell if an object found by the map is of type `B` or `D` using `dynamic_cast`. Here's the code:

```
  void foo(std::map<int,B*> inmap){
     std::map<int,B*>::iterator it=inmap.find([Something]);
     D *pd=dynamic_cast<D*>(it->second);
     if(pd!=nullptr){
        // You know it->second is pointing to an object of type D
     }
     else{
        // Just an ordinary type B
     }
  }
```

You'll have a better understanding of polymorphism if you can do this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/magic-spells